# Excel: Create two columns of pulldown lists with one dependent on another

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, multiple-columns, relational

This seems to be a straight forward question that I can't find an answer for.

I'm inputting a list of products in Excel. Our store has set Departments and Classes inside those departments.

I have one column marked "Department" which pulls (using data validation) from a NAMED LIST from another Sheet. [That is, in Validate: Settings, the source says "=departments" which is what I named that list of departments].

This works perfectly fine and I understand data validation. I have the entire Department column set to use data validation to show this list on each new record. Works every time and works well.

Here's the problem. The Classes are dependent on the Department. To make this SIMPLE imagine I have 2 departments (I really have approximately 40 departments and 100s of classes):

- Computers
- Monitors

Each department has it's own classes of products:

- Computers = Laptop, Desktop, Rack Mount, Server
- Monitors = LCD, CRT, OLED

To store these, I have column B on the second sheet with all the Classes for "Computers" and named that list "computers". I have the three monitors classes listed in Column C on the other sheet and named that list "monitors"

If the user picks the department Computers for a new product, the next column, Class should show the possible classes for Computers (Laptop, Desktop...)

From everything I've read, I should do an INDIRECT() lookup... I can do that pretty easily for individual cells in the column. I can go to row 4 and click on the Class cell and put in this formula for data validation:

```
 =INDIRECT($AF$4)
```

In this case "AF4" is a calculation which has the LOWER of the department with SUBSTITUTING the spaces in the name with underscores (then I use that same naming convention in my lists). For example:

```
 =LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(I17," ","_"))
```

As I explained, that works for individual cells. It does NOT work for the entire column. That is, I can't select the whole column and put in that formula... it is always attached to AF4 (or whatever I put in there). I need it to change for EACH ROW.

I've tried all these - none of them work.

```
 =INDIRECT(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,4))
 =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), "AF"))
 =INDIRECT(INDIRECT("AF"&ROW()))
```

Almost every time I get an error saying "The source currently evaluates to an error - Continue?" which means it never works :-(

I hope that's enough info for some Excel expert out there to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working with your example. I entered the departments in column A of Sheet2 and the products in column B, as such:

```
Computers   Laptop
Computers   Desktop
Computers   Rack Mount
Computers   Server
Monitors    LCD
Monitors    CRT
Monitors    OLED
```

I then set up a dynamic named range for column A to decrease the lookup load on Excel. I named the range "DeptsForProducts". It is important that you not only repeat the department name for each product row but also that the columns be sorted such that all products for the Computers department are together, all products for the Monitors row are together, etc.

Then, return to your original sheet (I used Sheet1; column A holds the validation for Department and column B is where I would like the validation for Products to appear). Select all of column B, open the data validation window, change the Allow: to List, and enter the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,MATCH(A1,DeptsForProducts,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(DeptsForProducts,A1))
```

You will get the "Source currently evaluates to an error" message again; ignore it and click Yes. Now, any cells in column B with Computers in column A will have a dropdown list of Laptop, Desktop, Rack Mount, or Server; any cells in column B with Monitors in column A will have a dropdown list of LCD, CRT, or OLED; and any cells with a blank or invalid department will have no dropdown list available.

Tested in Excel 2013.

Comment: Wow Nick! That works! there is a typo in your text (you call it DeptForProducts in one place and DeptsForProducts in another). I can make this work - thanks so much!

Comment: Two questions Nick: 1, my department pulldown has Computers, Computers, Computers in it... should I just make a distinct list to make that work? 2, in my file (it has a format I can't change - long story), the departments are in column I and the Classes are in column E - I can't seem to get your formula to work with those columns (I've got Sheet2 with Column A and B like you have above) - can you maybe explain what that formula is doing exactly?

Comment: Oops, fixed my typo! For Q1: yes, I used two separate lists. One list contains just departments; the other list contains departments and products within each department, with the departments being repeated for each product.

Comment: =OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,MATCH(I1,DeptsForProducts,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(DeptsForProducts,I1))

Comment: I got it - can't put code in these comments apparently

Comment: Perfect - I was about to suggest that one :) FYI, you can enter code "inline" using the ` symbol, like such `Code Here`